# Where did my Google Chrome go?

Tags: unity-dash

I installed Google chrome using a .deb package, however unable to find it under dash. Tough i can run it using terminal

Please tell me the path where i can find Google chrome and other applications installed, so that from there i may launch them by double click?

Comment: Go to /usr/share/applications/ directory.

Comment: also press "SUPER+A" to see all application in unity dash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that path must be: `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`
if you run it from terminal it will show in unity, and that just right click and `Lock to launcher`

---

[image: this is what you need]

---

Answer (score 2):

Two commands to use in a Terminal.

**whereis** 
e.g.: whereis google-chrome - will tell you the various places google-chrome can be found

and

**which**
e.g.: which google-chrome - will tell you where the executable is.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if your dash gone really bad, like other installed apps didn't showed up on dash, duplicate icons on dash, or else, you can just reset your dash this way:

1. Open **Home** directory, then unhide all files using `Ctrl+H`.
2. Browse to **.local/share** and delete a folder named **applications**, or you can move the folder somewhere to have a backup.
3. Check your dash now. But if something went even wrong you can just move the **applications** folder back, replace the existing folder if any.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your system. Your dash probably failed to incorporate the new installation into it's application registry. Restarting, or maybe just logging out and back in, should fix the problem.